# Unique Entity Types in an Archetype-based ECS

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, entity, entity-component-system

I am currently designing an Entity Component System (ECS) where each entity is of a unique type:

```
template <typename... ComponentTypes>
struct Entity
{
    using Signature = std::tuple<ComponentTypes...>;
    size_t ID;
};
```

This design decision has led to some unique challenges and I'm seeking advice on how to handle them.

1. **Non-contiguous Entity Storage**: The main pitfall for me is that it's
   harder for ***the user*** to store the entities contiguously, because they
   would need a container for each component type variation.
2. **Order-Independent Component Types**: The order of the Component types
   doesn't matter. For example, component types: `["Position", "Health"]`
   is the same as `["Health", "Position"]`. You can find the essence of
   how I did it here: [Link](https://godbolt.org/z/aqx7jo9Wd). I am basically sorting the
   types at compile-time.
3. **Archetype-Based Design**: I'm using an archetype-based design. I am
   using a type-erased archetype object, which I need to cast to the
   respective type to access the components. Each archetype stores a
   sparse set of Entities, along with a tuple of vectors for the
   components.
4. **Accessing Archetypes**: To access an archetype, you need to know the
   whole list of types the archetype stores. This is the main reason
   for the templated Entity.
5. **Strongly Typed Systems**: Systems are strongly typed at compile time,
   which is similar to how ECST does it.
6. **Entity Type Change**: Each time I add/remove a component, I need to
   change the type of the entity.
7. **Entity::Signature as Key**: The `Entity::Signature` acts as a key to
   know in which Archetype type the Entity resides, which would be
   faster than looping over all the Entities and checking if the IDs
   are equal.
8. **Heavy Template Metaprogramming**: I am heavily relying on template
   metaprogramming. This provides type safety, as the compiler checks that the types used
   with a template are valid for the operations the template performs.

I am interested in hearing your thoughts on this design decision and any potential pitfalls or improvements you might suggest. Thank you in advance for your insights!